# Animation in R without saving figures and without external software

Tags: r, matlab, animation, plot, figure

Is it possible to create an animation in R directly, as in Matlab, without actually saving figures and using external software? Just executing a script?

Consider the following example in Matlab.

```
t = (1:360) / 180 * pi;    % 360 angles in radians from 1 to 360 degrees
n = length(t);    % Length of vector
x = cos(t);    % Cosines
y = sin(t);    % Sines
f = figure;    % Create figure and its handle
hh = plot(2, 2, 'or', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r', 'MarkerSize', 10);    % Create plot and its handle
set(gca, 'XLim', [-1 1]);    % Set x axis limits
set(gca, 'YLim', [-1 1]);    % Set y axis limits
axis square; axis off;    % Set more properties for axes

while ishandle(f)    % Until the user closes the figure
  try    % Try this loop, if encouter an error just break the loop
    for ii = 1:n    % For all angles
      set(hh, 'XData', x(ii))    % Change point x coordinate
      set(hh, 'YData', y(ii))    % Change point y coordinate
      pause(0.01)    % Make a little pause
    end
  end
end
```

---

After **hrbrmstr**'s answer, I have tried this:

```
t <- (1:360) / 180 * pi
n <- length(t)
x <- cos(t)
y <- sin(t)

while(TRUE) {
  for (i in 1:n) {
    plot(x[i], y[i], ann=FALSE, pch=20, axes=FALSE, xlim=c(-1, 1), ylim=c(-1, 1), col="red", cex=4, asp=1)
    Sys.sleep(0.01)
  }
}
```

and it seems to be doing the job. Thanks!

I have also tried this:

```
t <- (1:360) / 180 * pi
n <- length(t)
x <- cos(t)
y <- sin(t)

while(TRUE) {
  for (i in 1:n) {
    plot.new()
    usr<-par("usr")
    par(usr=c(-1.1, 1.1, -1.1, 1.1))
    lines(x, y, col="green")
    points(x[i], y[i], pch=20, col="red", cex=4, asp=1)
    Sys.sleep(0.01)
  }
}
```

which is closer to what I had initially in mind. However I find R's "paper and pen" drawing model just terrible. Isn't there a way around that?

Comment: Did you search before asking this question?

Comment: I found animation packages, external software, but nothing as simple as in my question.

Comment: You may want something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29#Example_2

Comment: Thank you user1436187, I have just tried it - on my system it actually produced a 4MB gif image that unfortunately shows a static blurred image… I find R a bit frustrating, it seems that every instruction that I am used to write in Matlab easily is either impossible or gets disproportionately complex in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not about to try to figure out what all the matlab plotting is doing w/r/t aesthetics.

This:

```
while(TRUE) {
  barplot(sample(1:1000, 10))
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

"animates" a random bar chart display pretty well IMO and:

```
t <- (1:360) / 180 * pi
n <- length(t)
x <- cos(t)
y <- sin(t)

for (i in 1:n) {
  plot(x[1:i], y[1:i], type="p")
  Sys.sleep(0.15)
}
```

does one basic bit of "animation" of the points in one fashion and:

```
for (i in 1:n) {
  plot.new()
  points(x[1:i], y[1:i])
  Sys.sleep(0.15)
}
```

in another (though that one needs some work setting x & y limits to avoid graphics device errors).

All three stop when asked to "stop" by the GUI or when the `for` loop is done.

Not exactly "disproportionately complex". More like "not familiar to the matlab person".